# Multiple Trees with Hierarchical Data (Left and Right values)

Tags: php, mysql, database, hierarchy, nested-sets

What issues are associated with maintaining multiple tress within a single table?

The motivation for having multiple trees is to avoid excessive updates to all nodes when inserting a node at the start. Each of the trees are completely separate entities.

**Example Table:**

```
tree_id  | id  | lft | rgt | parent_id |   various fields . . .
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1        |  1  |  1  |  4  |   NULL    |   ...
1        |  2  |  2  |  3  |    1      |   ...
2        |  3  |  1  |  4  |   NULL    |   ...
2        |  4  |  2  |  3  |    3      |   ...
```

Comment: Please restate your question better. Simply answering "Yes" or "No" would satisfy your question the way it is currently formed.

Comment: @FinalForm thanks, is that better?

Comment: Yes. It makes sense to properly state the question, because people get points for answering your questions. And if that isn't your intended question, then it's not possible to answer a question that's not known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very common to store multiple trees in one table, just have to make sure the values that comprise a tree are stored correctly, otherwise it'll lead to data integrity issues like nonsensical tree constructions.

Suppose we have a binary tree, (like the one in your example). If a tree was 5 depth. ((2^n)-1) = (2^5 - 1) nodes would exist or 31 rows in the database which is trivial. Even at 10 depth it's still a small amount of rows, but would be a rather ginormous tree. And so having multiple trees, X, in there would be X((2^n)-1) = rows... in the database which isn't bad. So potentially a hundred trees could exist in one table and would only be 100k rows which is relatively small.

Additionally, suppose every new tree constructed was stored in its own table, then very quickly, the database would be filled with quite a bit of tables over time to match the number of trees that exist. And it just seems like not a good idea to make extra tables that are unneeded, adds unneeded complexity in the code side to have to access these multiple tables.

Looking at your table in detail, it doesn't quite look right in terms of columns, but I'm sure that table example is just something thrown up quickly to show us what you mean.

```
tree_id, node_id, left_node_id, right_node_id, various_fields...
```

Um, be sure to index those _id fields.

Comment: Sorry, that was meant to be (2^10-1) or 999 rows. A tree that is 10 depth is a huge freaking tree, and it's only taking up 999 rows.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer. I missed out two columns from the question...fixed in a second. Currently the table has a single tree with `id`, `parent_id`, `lft` and `rgt` indexed separately. I thought that it was probably better to index `lft` and `rgt` like that as opposed to using a composite index.

Comment: I have added a separate table which lists each different tree along with the initial node and have updated my scripts accordingly. It seems to be working great. Thanks again for your encouragement on this approach :-)

Comment: @LeaHayes Yep, no problem. Remember to index your _id columns, very important for the long run. And make sure the tables are InnoDB and not MyISAM